# Jmeter:Able to get the required value from XML,using the JSR223 PostProcessor.Need to Store it in a variable,so that I can be used across threads

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

1)  I get response in a XML format.

2)  I’m able to process the XML format using JSR223 PostProcessor.

3)  Also able to get the required value from XML response.

How do I store this value in a variable, so that it can be used across threads?
NOTE:

1)  Log.info is working correctly in JSR223 PostProcessor i.e the value gets printed correctly in the jmeter.log file , but when I use ${__setProperty(storeid, ${storeid})}; this is not working.

2)  I have added BeanShell Assertion too but still its not working.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move JMeter variable x to property y using `props` and `vars`

```
props.put("y", vars.get("x));
```

In your case both names are storeid